# Drupal site wide contact form permissions for all programmatically

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-contact-form

I am developing a drupal(7.x) module where I need to give **site wide contact form permissions for all programmatically**.

I want this programmatically :- 
[image]

I need help about this. If any one know how to do this please help me.

Thanks and regards

Gmw Raj

Comment: What do you mean by "for all"? For all users? for all roles? Please describe a little more about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

My problem solved by using this solution(Jaypan)

```
**<?php
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$menu)
{
  if(isset($menu['contact']))
  {
    $menu['contact']['access callback'] = TRUE;
  }
}
?>**
```

visit this [link](https://drupal.org/node/2121975#comment-8009919)